# I am trying to sort this array in python using selection sort algorithm but it doesn't give the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting, for-loop, selection-sort

This is my code :

```
a = [3,7,10,1,9,6,8,5,4]
for i in a:
    if i < len(a) - 1:
        min = i
        for j in a:
            if j < len(a):
                if a[j] < a[min]:
                    min = j
        if min != i:
            temp = a[min]
            a[min] = a[i]
            a[i] = temp
        j += 1
    i += 1

print(a)
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
[3, 8, 10, 5, 1, 7, 9, 6, 4]
```

What am I doing wrong in this? I shall be very grateful for an elaborated answer to my question.

Comment: To begin with, you think `i` and `j` are indexes (0, 1, ...), but they are element values (3, 7, ...). It makes no sense to compare a value with array's length or take another value using this value as index.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But then, how will I give a condition to : 
1. Check if the value of i is less than equal to the number of elements - 1
2. Similarly check if the value of j is equal to the number of elements

Comment: Exactly the same way you have it now. It's just that `i` and `j` should be indices, not values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have confused in your code the index and the value of the array for that specific index. I have tried to keep the code as similar as possible to yours but I have renamed `i` to `indexI` and `j` to `indexJ` so that it is clearer that they are indexes and not values. I also changed `min` to `indexMinimum`:

```
a = [3,7,10,1,9,6,8,5,4]

for indexI in range(len(a)):
    
    indexMinimum = indexI
    
    for indexJ in range(indexI+1, len(a)):
        if a[indexJ] < a[indexMinimum] :
            indexMinimum = indexJ
            
    if a[indexMinimum] != a[indexI]:
        a[indexI], a[indexMinimum] = a[indexMinimum], a[indexI]

print ("The arranged array is: ", str(a))
```

Hope you find it useful :)